# When video has finished playing start audio?

Tags: jquery, audio, video

How can one trigger an audio element to start as soon as a video in HTML5 video tag has finished playing? I am thinking it would be with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
function listen(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) // W3C DOM
    elem.addEventListener(evnt, func, false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
        var r = elem.attachEvent("on" + evnt, func);
        return r;
    }
    else window.alert('I\'m sorry, I\'m afraid I can\'t do that.');
}

listen("ended", document.getElementById('myvideo1'), DoSomething);

function DoSomething() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('sound-1');
    audio.play();
}
```

If you have any further questions, see this resource:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-ended

Comment: thanks, I have set up this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/3dSra/15/  could you show me how to use the code above please?

Comment: Have a look at the code above, ended up going a different route. Toss that in place of the current JS and it works.